# .NET 6 web api project needs to export XML and JSON

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a web api project that has some actions (most) that need to export JSON, and some (only a few) that need to export as XML.

Since XML isn't supported by default, i've added the

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
})
```

bit to my Startup.cs, and added to the Action that needs XML:

```
[Produces("application/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportAsKML(Guid id)
```

And this works for that method, but now ALL of my controller actions default to XML.  How can I keep the default to JSON, but only use XML for a certain few actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the order of your formats in OutputFormatters?

Accroding to the offcial document :Formatters are evaluated in the order they're inserted, where the first one takes precedence.
:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-mvc-to-use-a-custom-formatter

check the order of the formats:
[image]
when I debug:
[image]
the default format become xml with out other settings,

in this order，
[image]

[image]